# No Bootloader after clean install

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader, surface

I tried to install Ubuntu on a Surface Pro 3 and the installation worked without any errors.

After trying to reboot there seems to be no bootloader (boots directly into uefi settings).

Booting with a live-cd and chrooting into my system gives me the following:

```
root@ubuntu:/# efibootmgr 
efibootmgr: Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0001": Input/output error
efibootmgr: Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0003": Input/output error
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 10 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0000,0001,0003
Boot0000  Windows Boot Manager
Boot0004* USB Drive
```

My system is:

```
    Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 241874842 240824219 114.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  241874944 250068991   8194048   3.9G Linux swap
```

And i also tried reinstalling grub following the [guide](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Reparatur/).

Reinstalling grub gives me the following error:

```
root@ubuntu:/# grub-install --boot-directory=/boot /dev/sda
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
efibootmgr: Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0001": Input/output error
efibootmgr: Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0003": Input/output error
efibootmgr: Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0001": Input/output error
efibootmgr: Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0003": Input/output error
efibootmgr: Could not set variable Boot0001: Input/output error
efibootmgr: Could not prepare boot variable: Input/output error
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

Boot-repair returns:
http://pasted.co/3fc673a5

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Any idea what Boot00001 and 0003 are or were? You can try delete `sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B` where XXXX is 0001 and/or 0003.

Comment: If I trz to delete them I get the following message:  `efibootmgr: Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0001": Input/output error` and the same for Boot0003. Unfortunately I have no Idea what they are/were

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

If that doesn't work, boot from a live CD, and run the `bootrepair` program.

Comment: `grub-install /dev/sda` returns : `root@ubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
efibootmgr: Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0001": Input/output error
efibootmgr: Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0003": Input/output error
efibootmgr: Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0001": Input/output error
efibootmgr: Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0003": Input/output error
efibootmgr: Could not set variable Boot0001: Input/output error
efibootmgr: Could not prepare boot variable: Input/output error
Installation finished. No error reported.
`.

Comment: @JustusSchock - And bootrepair?

Comment: edited in original post